# why console.log results empty at first click?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, console.log

Take a look to [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dXWrAE) pen.

Open the console of the browser then click on the `button`.

You will see that console's results is executed but it is empty at first time.   Why?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fysKq.png)

Second click will show half of input result.

Answer (score 2):

because you are assigning the value of id="input" to the string before you change the inner html .

change the code like this

```
var input = document.getElementById('input'),
number = document.getElementById('special');

number.addEventListener("click", function(e) {


   input.innerHTML += e.target.innerHTML;

   var currentString = input.innerHTML;
  console.log(currentString);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

At first there is nothing in `id='input'` and you are concating button text with `id='input'` so there is nothing shows in the first click. so if you want result `'text'` in the first click do like this.

```
var input = document.getElementById('input'),
    number = document.getElementById('special');

  number.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

  var currentString = input.innerHTML;
      console.log(currentString);
      input.innerHTML += e.target.innerHTML;
      currentString = input.innerHTML;
      console.log(currentString);

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

During the first console.log call, `currentString` is not defined because there is nothing inside the input box yet. The next line then sets the value of the input box, `e.target.innerHTML`, which is equal to the value of the `.innerHTML` of the button you just clicked. The next line then successfully logs `currentString` because it has now been set.

Answer (score 0):

```
1     number.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
2    
3          var currentString = input.innerHTML;
4          console.log(currentString);
5          input.innerHTML += e.target.innerHTML;
7          console.log(currentString);
8    
9     });
```

Line 3: input.innerHTML at this point has no value.

Line 4: You try to log it, which is empty.

Line 5: You add to the innerHTML of the input the text from the button.

Line 6: Add to the innerHTML the value from the button.

Line 7: Console.log will still return an empty string as you didn't reassign the new value to currentString.

Answer (score 0):

Change `<div id="input"></div>` to `<div id="input">text</div>` in your HTML, if are expecting value to be printed on console on first click. As at first instance, `input.innerHTML` will be empty as you have not assigned any value. As simple as that.